# PIC problem: Touching the crystal capacitor makes the system slows down

Tags: pic, capacitor, high-speed, clock-speed

I am experiencing a very unusual problem (at least for me). When I touch with my fingers, or the oscilloscope probes, on the crystal or it's capacitors, the PIC runs slower...and A LOT slower then it should...with my fingers, most of the time it comes back to the real speed, but with the probes, it hangs forever.

I am running the PIC18F2550 at 48MHz with a 20MHz crystal...I supose I am maybe changing the capacitance "seen" by the PIC across the crystal and the oscillation circuit is going nuts..does it makes any sense? And if it does, what may I do to correct it?

EDIT:

The pictures below shows the circuit. The blue picture is the Bottom Layer of a 2 layer FR4 170Tg/290T ENIG board. I have highlighted the oscillator's traces, it's possible to see the ground plane, connected to both capacitors and the crystal in the middle, between them. The red picture is the Top Layer, where there is a big (and highlighted) ground plane, and some traces for two LEDs. There is also a transparent mix of the Top and Bottom layer, so see how they interact with each other. It's possible to see the PIC's orientation and schematics of this part of the project by the oscillator traces.

The problem only appears when the OSC1 capacitor is completly touched, or the OSC1 pin at the PIC is touched. Touching the traces or OSC2 capacitor doesn't bring any harm, as expected.

The Crystal:http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/NX5032GA-20.000000MHZ-LN-CD-1/644-1039-1-ND/1128911

The Crystal's Capacitors:http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/12061A150JAT2A/478-1439-1-ND/564471?cur=USD

EDIT2: The finger can have a 5pF to 15pF capacitance, so probably there is no much that can be done...http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/01101a.pdf (page 2)
Removing the ground plane as pointed out in the answers is worst.

[image: Bottom Layer]

[image: Top Layer]

[image: Bottom and Top Layer]

The Oscilloscope waveforms:

OSC1 before being touched:

[image: OSC1 before being touched]

OSC1 after being touched:

[image: OSC1 after being touched]

OSC2 before OSC1 being touched:

[image: OSC2 before OSC1 being touched]

OSC2 after OSC1 being touched:

[image: OSC2 after OSC1 being touched]

Comment: 20MHz to 48Mhz you ask? See the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/39632c.pdf) page 24. It has a 96MHz PLL with an input of 4MHz, so divide 20MHz by 5 using prescaler, and input to the 96MHZ PLL, which has a divide by 2 on the other side for 48MHz.

Comment: I am using HSPLL, since I have USB communications

Comment: When you probe the crystal, probe on the OSC2 pin as this is the low impedance side. Use the 10x setting. Probing the OSC1 side may throw it out even if the circuit is okay.

Comment: Also : is the case of the crystal connected to 0V? It should be.

Comment: @OliGlaser the 10x probing worked well...I have a ground plane beneath the crystal, so I think this is the problem, since my finger and the ground plane will be another capacitor seen by the circuit...(I will provide the files shortly)

Comment: @ChetanBhargava Altium Designer...the transparent image could be done in Altium, but I made it in Photoshop, since I was already there...

Comment: @mFeinstein - no, that's fine thanks - I'll take a proper look at all the details and post something tomorrow, as it needs more than a few minutes to answer this one in detail (5:30am here, so I'm off to get some sleep now) +1 for a well presented question.

Comment: @OliGlaser I already changed the layoutm removing the ground plane around the OSC1...I will place this proposed solution (or at least "attenuator") later as well...4:30am here ;)

Comment: @mFeinstein Removing the ground plane is a bad idea, generally you do need to calculate your trace to ground plane capacitance and reduce your decoupling by that amount. oscillators are some of the easiest radiators you can have and that ground plane greatly reduces the ability it can radiate.

Comment: @Kortuk that's what I had in mind when I placed it around...but now how may I reduce or eliminate this touch problem? Or it's impossible to eliminate at all?
The problem only appears when I touch the OSC1 pin or the solder joint in the capacitor or the crystal, so maybe it's impossible to eliminate at all I think...

Comment: @mFeinstein - I added an answer, sorry for the delay. What you are seeing is probably not cause for concern, but try testing over your temperature range, and also altering supply voltage within specified range. Also if you can check the signal properly (i.e. take into account loading or use a FET probe) to see whether the drive level is low or the crystal is overdriven/distorting, do this.

Comment: @OliGlaser How do I know if the drive level is low, or the crystal is overdriven/distorting? What am I expecting to see?

Comment: @mFeinstein - Ideally a nice sine wave of reasonable amplitude  - I will add a couple of scope shots to my answer.

Comment: @mFeinstein - Okay, I added some scope captures and a bit more discussion. Note that I was unable to stop the oscillator using either probe or finger. This in itself does not mean your design is bad, as the micro/crystal/frequency is different - however it certainly raises questions you need to look into (assuming you are intending to make a few of these)

Comment: @OliGlaser maybe the PLL circuit is having trouble with the finger, and not the crystal itself?

Comment: @mFeinstein - I doubt it, the PLL is after the oscillator circuitry so shouldn't make any difference. The dsPIC I used as an example also had the PLL active during my tests. If you want to make sure, try your circuit without the PLL active. First thing I'd try is heating it up a bit (hair dryer or hot air gun on low) to see if it stops. You are using HS mode for the oscillator aren't you?

Comment: @OliGlaser I am using the HSPLL mode, my assumption was that the PLL was shutting down or stabilizing in some other frequency, since when I remove the finger the board is still very slow. Since I dont understand much of the oscillator's circuit, I was assuming that since the system was still functioning, so there was still some oscillation going on, and since it was so much slower, maybe it was just will no PLL..I will see the speeds in more detail and verify if it fits..

Comment: @mFeinstein - I think it's quite likely the main oscillator stops, and the internal oscillator is taking over if it's set up that way (I can't recall about the 18F2550 but other PICs have a failsafe mode where this happens (it will be mentioned in the datasheet). There will definitely still be oscillation going on if you are seeing the part work but just more slowly - to confirm it's the internal oscillator, try setting it to a different frequency, touch the crystal to stop it, and see if the speed of e.g. an LED flashing changes.

Comment: @OliGlaser, I measured OSC1 and OSC2 before and after the finger pressed OSC1 and slowed the system. There is a 20MHz perfect sine wave going on before and after, on both OSC1 and OSC2, the only difference I can see is that before I touch it, the OSC1 sine wave Vpp is 2.4V and after it becomes 2.62V, and OSC2 is 4.8V and after it becomes 4.96V...I will upload the scope shots in a while

Comment: @OliGlaser the LED that was blinking at 150.4ms period becomes 7.64s, which is 50,8 times slower...

Comment: @OliGlaser I just placed the oscilloscope's images.

Comment: @mFeinstein - Hmmmmm, I think we may have a red herring here,  those scope shots look like a oscillator working well to me. Now I'm a bit puzzled - what indication are you using to determine that the micro slows down? Can you add a check for the external oscillator stable, and/or the internal oscillator being active and light an LED to indicate this, then perform the test and see if it's really the oscillator causing issues. The relevant bits hould be in the OSCCON register. If there is a PLL lock indicator bit check this also.

Comment: @OliGlaser I may do this tomorrow...but in a quick search I found that the finger can hava a capacitance of 5pF to 15pF which could double the capacitance os OSC1...and the osciloscope also have a 15pF capacitance...so I am figuring there is no much that can be done...

Comment: @OliGlaser I am looking for a new crytal with a shield (mine doest have one). As far as I can see the ESR and Load capacitance should be as small as possible right? Are there  any other parameters I should pay attention?

Comment: @OliGlaser I am changing the PCB design and I am tinking about changing the Xtal to this one: http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/7B-20.000MEEQ-T/887-1303-1-ND/2207885
what do you think?
I like the shielding (the original didnt have one) but the leads to OSC1 and OSC2 will never have the same lenght...I thinks that happens with all Xtals this size, so this small difference shouldnt matter right?

Comment: Although I have never used the crystal package you were using initially, I have used that type of crystal in a few designs with no problems, so I think it couldn't hurt to change it. Attention to the layout (try and get the crystal as close as possible with no other traces crossing it's traces) as shown in my answer will do the most good I imagine though. A small difference in trace lengths shouldn't matter, no.

Comment: @OliGlaser how much distance the other traces in other layers should have from the crystal's traces? I have some pretty close...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a look at things and although what you are seeing when you load the high impedance pin of the oscillator is to be expected, it is still possible your circuit is not optimal.

Ideally the crystal traces would be as short as possible, with no high frequency/current traces crossing those traces at any point (also running under the micro is not ideal). In short the crystal and it's load capacitors will be as close to the pins as is practical.
Also, a ground "shield" trace running around the outside of the oscillator traces, and a local ground plane underneath the crystal can help reduce any external noise issues. These would be connected directly to the microcontrollers Vss at one point (if a ground plane layer is present, the capacitors can be grounded through vias to this)

I don't know what the other traces crossing your crystal traces are carrying (so how much of an issue they would be), but be aware of issues here. Also the traces are longer than is ideal.

Here is an example layout:

[image: Oscillator Layout]

To test how marginal your circuit may be, you need to see if it starts and runs okay over your operating temperature range. So cool/heat the circuit as necessary and cycle power to see if the oscillator starts correctly. If you apply a slight change and it doesn't start, you need to fix it.
Similarly, you need to determine how susceptible it is to noise. This is difficult to do "scientifically", but placing a noisy circuit (e.g. something that switches quickly with high current) near the oscillator can give you an idea of how easily it can be affected. How much of a concern this is depends on whether your circuit is intended for e.g. automotive/industrial or less noisy environments.

If you discover the circuit is marginal, then it could be that the drive is too high or low, both of which can cause issues. For a high frequency like 20MHz, a higher drive level is needed, so with a PIC this would correspond to the HS setting. If the drive level is too high, a series resistance can be included to adjust the drive as necessary (or with the PIC XT mode could be tried). Loading capacitance needs to be calculated/adjusted to include stray capacitance (CL1 || CL2 + Cstray - see app notes below for details) Another possibility is the crystal itself is not ideal, so trying another crystal is also an option.

When testing, ideally a 100x or FET probe would be used, and AC coupling the scope input will reduce loading also. If a 10x probe is used (or even a FET probe ideally), then you need to account for the extra capacitance by lowering the load capacitor on that side.

There are various ways of testing your oscillator to make sure it's stable/reliable. As well as the temperature tests, testing adequate drive can be done e.g. adding pot in series with the crystal, and increasing until the oscillator fails. When you reach this point the potentiometers measured value should be at least 5 times the crystal ESR to provide adequate gain over all conditions. This, and other methods of testing are discussed in the first link of helpful App notes below:

[Making Your Oscillator Work](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/appnotes/00949a.pdf)  (pretty good note on various methods of testing)
[ST Oscillator Design Guide](http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/APPLICATION_NOTE/CD00221665.pdf)  (layout diagram above came from this note)
[EFM Oscillator Design Considerations](http://cdn.energymicro.com/dl/an/pdf/an0016_efm32_oscillator_design_considerations.pdf)
[Crystal Oscillator Troubleshooting Guide - Freescale](http://www.freescale.com/files/microcontrollers/doc/app_note/AN3208.pdf)  (examines common problems)
[Design an Oscillator to Match your Application - Maxim](http://www.maximintegrated.com/app-notes/index.mvp/id/5265)  (lots of useful theory)
[Oscillators For Microcontrollers - Intel](http://ecee.colorado.edu/~mcclurel/iap155.pdf) (old, but still very relevant)

---

**Experimental data and scope shots**

To add some direct data obtained by myself to the above, I took a dsPIC prototype with a 4MHz crystal (sorry, no boards with a 20MHz crystal to hand - the principle is exactly the same in any case) which was made up on breadboard (so an "ideal" layout is not really possible) and probed both OSC pins with a standard 10x probe. The purposes were to find out whether I could stop the oscillator, and to take a couple of example scope shots to see how it was performing.

The result was probing either side did not stop the oscillator, but it looks like the crystal is slightly overdriven (espcially since extra loading should reduce the gain a little)
Touching the pins did not even cause it to stop, however pressing firmly on the lead (high impedance side) of the 1 MΩ resistor I had put across the oscillator created enough capacitance to cause the amplitude to drop and the clipping to stop (a rough indication a little more load capacitance or a series resistor reduce drive slightly would be a good idea)

The overdrive is not of a concern for a breadboard prototype, since the oscillator does it's job and is very solid. However, the overdrive could eventually cause premature failure so would be an issue when designing for production. Ideally you would want enough drive to make it difficult to disturb the oscillator, but not too much so as to overdrive the crystal (so a nice sine wave at both sides).
This is easier said than done, as it requires the correct tools/approach, so is why in many cases engineers just follow the recommendations and hope for the best. This is not the best approach, as what may work fine at 25°C may not work at 35°C. So although it may be difficult to do, testing the oscillators performance at design time may save a lot of trouble later on.

Anyway, enough preaching, here are the pictures:

Board (sorry for bad lighting) - notice although it's messy, the crystal and caps (blue) are very close to the pins. The 1MΩ resistor across OSC1 and OSC2 is closest to the edge.

[image: Board picture]

OSC 2 low impedance side (slightly overdriven):

[image: dsPIC Low Impedance side]

OSC1 pin high impedance side:

[image: dsPIC high impedance side]

High impedance side with finger pressed firmly onto OSC1 (using resistor lead mentioned) Notice reduced amplitude and sine wave shape:

[image: dsPIC high impedance side finger]

Answer (score 4):

I think that maybe that pair of capacitors usually in the 10's of pF are not well chosen. Check the crystal specs. I'd suggest 10, 15 or 22pF but it depends on the crystal and up to some extent to the layout and oscillator circuit. Microchip datasheets also have some advice on oscillator components. Whenever you touch a oscillator circuit with your finger or a probe, you are basically adding a capacitive load which usually dampens the oscillation and stops the clock but some times (it could be your case) make the crystal oscillate into a harmonic frequency. It's not so unusual.

Comment: I am using 15pF

Answer (score 4):

To first understand what is happening you need to understand *HOW* oscillators work and XCO's in particular.  XCO = Crystal Controlled Oscillator.  X is short hand for Crystal AKA XTal.

Fundamentally an oscillator is simply an amplifier that has 180 degrees phase shift at the frequency of interest.  If you can support that, whilst suppressing other phases then your oscillator will run at the frequency at which the phase is 180 degrees and no other.

Typically, simple oscillator are logic inverters with the output driving through a delay element, or even a filter back to it's input.  SO the output will be low impedance and the input will be high impedance.  Crystals can be manufactured and easily tuned to given delays/filter characteristics very reproduce-ably so are a natural fit.  The capacitors you use with them are used to filter out (in some cases) harmonic/tones that you want to suppress, since crystals are resonant devices, they can have overtones and harmonics.

In other cases it is desired to "pull" the XCO to a slightly different frequency by adversly affecting the delay through the crystal.  You would do that by changing the C value of the input side of the amplifier used in the oscillator.  This change in C, changes the delay, which represents a different value of phase for a given frequency.

Not all oscillators are as sensitive, but it is well known that certain types are.  And indeed, some manufacturers have recommendations on how to lay out your PCB to prevent stray fileds, leakage and EMI/RFI from affecting your frequency and even jitter.

The TLDR version:

1. don't touch the XTal or the Input to the oscillator.  Your result is not surprising.
2. if you must, as mentioned in the comments, probe the output side of the oscillator's amplifier as it will have much lower impedance and *MIGHT* be able to handle the increased loading.
3. Or use a low C probe - like a FET probe on your 'scope

Comment: Some MCU's have clock output pins which you can use to probe the clock signal.

Comment: exactly, that's a good point to raise for that case.  There are many variants.

Comment: @rawbrawb could you look at the pictures I added to the question, and give me some recommendations? Thank you!

Comment: @mFeinstein the first ting I notice is that your XTal is far from the pins, the 2nd thing I notice is that trace capacitiance is different from one side of the Xtal to the other.  Removing the ground plane does reduce the stray capacitance but increases the coupling capacitance to potential aggressors signals (as Kortuk pointed out).  You've shown so far that they system is sensitive (your "finger" experiment) could you get a better placement?

Comment: @rawbrawb I was thinking the same when I was designing the board, but since it worked well in the protoboard, I figured the traces differences and distance wouldnt be a problem, since in the breadboard things were a lot far away from the pins. The board is very small with lots of stuff, so I dont think I might place them any closer, not in the same layer, and placing in another layer will add the inductance of the vias. What do you think of leaving the ground plane in the bottom (blue layer) and only removing the ground plane from the top (red layer)?

Comment: @rawbrawb I just placed the oscilloscope's images, could you please take a look at them? I think it's the PLL circuit that is going nuts, since there is still 20MHz all the time...

Comment: @mFeinstein  things to check/report, what mode of crystal are you using?  Reading the datasheet there are various configurations of R and C's and Serial cut XTals are NOT recommended.  Also note that the OSC1 input goes into the input of the phase comparator for the PLL so will be sensitive.  If that is what is causing the problems then I contend the easy solution is STOP putting your finger on it!  and shield that input.

Comment: @rawbrawb I will stop placing my finger on it ;) but I just want to try to make it "user-proff" since this will be used in a 100 pound Combat Robot and the team loves to mess around with the electronics.
I am using HSPLL mode with a 20MHz crystal and 15pF capacitors as the question states.

Comment: @mFeinstein 20MHZ is but one spec.  What kind of XTal?  That might be very important, you may be mis-operating it, or you may not.

Comment: I placed the XTal and the capacitors links in the question..

Comment: @mFeinstein page 1 from Xtal manufacturer app note (pdf) http://www.ndk.com/catalog/AN-CU_ROC_e.pdf the fact that the F doesn't vary very much means that the XTal is _OK_ but try these component values.  You're probably overdriving the XTal.

Comment: @rawbrawb which part?